# How to pass asp.net webpage variables to android activity class?

Tags: android, asp.net

I was to trying to connect Ms sql file directly from my Android Activity file, but I couldn't do that. So I created asp.net webpage to connect ms sql so that I can get the data. 
However, I don't know how to pass the data from asp.net webpage to Android Activity class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Fetch the data using a service into a JSON from the asp.net** page and then **parse the JSON** in the **android app**. This is how you will be able to exchange data and the store it in a db from android app.

Comment: Thanks But Would you show me some sample codes how to make JSon for asp.net and android please?

Comment: please go to [aspx to json]( http://bytes.com/topic/asp-net/answers/877861-how-return-json-data-aspx-page) for the conversion and [json to android](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-json-parsing-tutorial/) and accept the answer please :)

Comment: so did you found the answer appropriate?

Comment: Sorry, but it's bit hard to understand. Is there any simple way to pass variable from asp.net to android?